# The MU-puzzle from GEB

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

The MUI system only uses the three letters **M**,**U**,and **I** to make strings. The system has four rules that allow you to make new strings out of existing strings by manipulating them. Rules 1 and 2 lengthen the strings while rules 3 and 4 shorten the strings.

The MU puzzle gives you **MI** as your initial string or "axiom" and asks if you can obtain the string **MU** only by applying the four rules to the axiom.

---

### RULE 1:

If you possess a string whose last letter is **I**, you can add on a **U** at the end.

***MI => MIU***

---

### RULE 2:

Suppose you have **M*x***. Then you may add **M*xx*** to your collection.

***MIU => MIUIU***

---

### RULE 3:

If **III** occurs in one place of the strings in your collection, you may make a new string with **U** in place of **III**.

***MIII => MU***

---

### RULE 4:

If **UU** occurs inside one of your strings, you can drop it.

***MIUU => MI***

---

So working from **MI**, I notice that using only Rule 2 you can determine what any theorem of consecutive Rule 2 usage is with the following formula:

**M**+ (**I** * 2^*x*) where *x* is the number of times Rule 2 is applied to the axiom **MI**.

So if *x*=  0 and Rule 2 is applied 0 times, then **MI => M**+ (**I** * 2^0) **=> M**+ (**I** * 1) **=> MI**

And if *x*=  1 and Rule 2 is applied 1 time, then **MI => M**+ (**I** * 2^1) **=> M**+ (**I** * 2) **=> MII**

And if *x*=  2 and Rule 2 is applied 2 times, then **MI => M**+ (**I** * 2^2) **=> M**+ (**I** * 4) **=> MIIII**

And so on...

Lets call this the ***Equation of Rule 2***

---

I also noticed that working backwards from the elusive **MU**, I used Rule 3 (backwards) to get **MIII**. Using the *Equation of Rule 2* we find the **MIII** cannot be obtained using Rule 2 alone, since there is no way 2^x can equal 3.

So **MU** has to become a longer and more complex string before it becomes its short form. Using Rule 4 (backwards) **MU** becomes **MUUU** and then using Rule 3 (also backwards) **MUUU** becomes **MIIIIIIIII**, that's nine **I**s, six for the **UU** that disappears (using Rule 4) and three for the **U** needed to make **MU** possible.

There is an equation that describes how many **I**s you can have to obtain **MU** using Rules 3 and 4. You need *y* number of six-**I**-sets plus a three-**I**-set.

**M** + (6 *y* +3) **I**

Lets call this the ***Equation of Rules 3 & 4***

---

The *Equation of Rule 2* grows the string and the *Equation of Rules 3 & 4* shrinks it back down. The variable *x* describes the amount of times Rule 2 is applied and the equation returns the number of **I**s. The variable *y* describes the amount of times Rule 4 will be applied and the equation returns the number of **I**s.

If we set these equations equal to one another we can pull out the proper numbers that will allow **MI** to be built up to a theorem that can be broken down to **MU**.

6 *y* +3 = 2^*x*

Rule 1 let's us drop the + 3 since we can just add **U** to the a string ending with **I**.

6 *y* = 2^*x*

This creates a curve and from that curve if we find a whole number *x* that produces a whole number *y* we find the path from **MI** to **MU**. How do I find those whole numbers using the equation?

I don't want the answer to this **MI => MU** problem since I know it's coming up in the book but any insight to the system would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For any integer solution $(x,y)$ to $6y=2^x$, both sides have to be divisible by the same numbers, so in particular by the same primes.

This condition characterizes completely all formulae that can derive **MU** from **MI**, so after you derived it you should think about what this condition implies about the number of $I$ and $U$ that can occur in a formula at the same time.

The lesson to learn from this system is that it is not easy to characterize which formulae can be generated by a system of simple rules. It all boils down to come up with invariants of the words that can be expressed, just as you will do when you examine the primes that divide both sides of your equation and the corresponding implications.

---

To further clarify, I'll try to stick to the terms you used.
Let $W$ be the set of all theorems that can be deduced by applying the rules 1-4 on the axiom $MI\in W$.

Let $S$ denote the set of all possible strings you can build with the letters $\{M,U,I\}$.

Then $W\subseteq S$ and for a given word $w\in S$ the membership problem of $w\in W$ is to decide whether $w\in W$ or not. In this case, you want to solve the membership problem for $MU\in W$.

In general, these problems are hard, so what one would like is to have an easy 'proof', or 'certificate', that either $w\in W$ or $w\not\in W$. One way to show that $w\in W$ is to give a construction, but that may be hard to achieve, and this does not really help for arguing that $w\not\in W$.

At this point, one can use invariants to help with things. An invariant for $W$ can be considered as a map $\phi: S\rightarrow Y\cup N$ where $\phi(w)\in N$ implies $w\not\in W$ but $\phi(w)\in Y$ gives no information whether $w\in W$ or not. So it is a formalization of the necessary condition $\phi(w)\in Y \quad \forall w\in W$. In particular, the nice thing about the invariant is that it holds for the axiom and is invariant under application of the rules, that is if $w'$ comes from $w$ by applying some rule, then $\phi(w)\in W$ implies $\phi(w')\in W$. Invariants can therefore be found by examining the rules and thus systematically constructed.

In your case, you can consider maps that map a word $w\in S$ to some algebraic expression in the number of letters $U$ and $I$ appearing in the word. For example, if the set of theorems $W'$ is defined by
$$MU\in W'$$ and $$replace\, U\, by\, IU\, or\, I$$ then you can show that the number of $U$ in every word in $W'$ is at most $1$. Then $\phi(w)=\#U $ and $Y=1$ and $N=\{2,...\}$.

For the $MU$ puzzle, you can find an invariant of the language $W$ that involves the rest of the number of $I$s after dividing by some small natural numbers, and in particular it is closely related to the analysis you already did. You can then check it against the word $MU$ to decide how its construction may or may not work.

Invariants can be seens as a shortcut to decide the membership problem if they can be applied, since they are normally way easier to check. If the membership problem can be completely decided by some invariant, then computing the invariant is often as complicated as the original membership problem.

Comment: By "formulae" in the phrase "characterize which formulae" could you say theorem, as in a result of the systems rules applied to an axiom? 

Could you expand this bit: "come up with invariants of the words that can be expressed"?

Thanks for you answer and taking the time to read my question.

Just curious, have you read GEB?

Comment: I added some stuff. feel free to ask again in case i was not clear enough. I did not read GEB (in fact, i don't know what this stands for), but the MU problem is a popular problem that shows that formal languages may not be easy to characterize. in fact, this is a major issue when considering building compilers, where the theory of formal languages can help to make the membership problem easily decidable.